# Error adding device: unsupported configuration: only supports passthrough accessmode

Tags: virt-manager

With virt-manager 2.2.1, I'm trying to create a shared directory between an Arch Linux host and a Kali guest.

I went to "Add New Virtual Hardware" → "Filesystem":

[image: virt-manager screenshot]

Clicking "Finish", I get this error message:

```
Error adding device: unsupported configuration: only supports passthrough accessmode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addhardware.py", line 1351, in _add_device
    self.vm.add_device(dev)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 408, in add_device
    self._redefine_xmlobj(xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 417, in _redefine_xmlobj
    self._redefine_xml_internal(origxml, newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 395, in _redefine_xml_internal
    self._define(newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 999, in _define
    self.conn.define_domain(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 612, in define_domain
    return self._backend.defineXML(xml)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4048, in defineXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainDefineXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: only supports passthrough accessmode
```

Is there a way to fix this and have a shared directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With [virtiofs](https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io/)

In virt-manager 4.0.0, this is how I created a shared directory (and I didn't run into any error yet):

### On the host

1. Create the shared directory on the host: `sudo -u libvirt-qemu mkdir ~/vm/arch_linux/shared`
2. In virt-manager's GUI for your VM, press "Add Hardware" and select "Filesystem":

[image: Add new Virtual Hardware: Filesystem]

### Inside the guest

Mount the shared directory: `sudo mount -t virtiofs /hostshare ~/shared`

### Regarding "Target path"

In this example, I used `/hostshare` as the "Target path". In virt-manager's XML config, this property is called "target dir". This is more an identifier than a path for the guest OS.

According to the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html):

> Note that despite its name, the target dir is an arbitrary string called a mount tag that is used inside the guest to identify the shared file system to be mounted. It does not have to correspond to the desired mount point in the guest.

Answer (score 4):

I had to change the driver from "Handle" to "Path":

[image: virt-manager shared dir config]

These are the settings and commands that made the shared directory work:

In virt-manager:

- Driver: Path
- Mode: Mapped
- Write Policy: Immediate

Permissions set on host for the shared directory:

- `sudo chgrp kvm shared/`
- `chmod 770 shared/`

Mount the shared directory in the guest:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio /hostshare /home/guest/shared
```

The `/hostshare` part is the "Target Path" defined with virt-manager.

In the guest, the shared directory is at `/home/guest/shared`.

Comment: Note that this requires 9pfs which [apparently isn't very well supported](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1119043).

Comment: @BrianZ: Fair enough. For the current (4.0.0) version of virt-manager, the options (type mount, driver handle) given in this answer aren't available anymore so I added [a new, separate, answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606816/error-adding-device-unsupported-configuration-only-supports-passthrough-access/705442#705442).